# SASS : Bridge table won't work when browsing the cube

Tags: data-warehouse

[image: Data Source View]

As described in the data source view schema in the picture above, I have a transaction fact table, the GL_Hierarchy dimension,the AccountList dimension and a bridge table that links between them. Here is an example of each dimension

The GL_Hierarchy dimension is a Parent/Child dimension :

[image]

The AccountList dimensions contains all the accounts of the general ledger

[image]

The bridge dimension links between an account and one/many categories of the GL hierarchy (Many to Many relationship)

[image]

When browsing my cube I want to the see the amount of the transactions and drill down through the hierarchy

When filtering only by account everything works fine

[image]

But as soon as I want to filter by using GL_Hierarchy attribute "Category Description" the results are wrong, the accounts are recurrent for every category as if there was no bridge dimension

[image]

I'm helpless and can't manage to make it work.

Thank you.